# Not all macros replaced?

Tags: c++, macros

Kindly check my sample code http://ideone.com/6xS1xg . The aim of the code is to show the problem in minimalistic way possible.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define myNode NodeP
#define f(x) fp(x##NodeStr)

int fp(void *  x)
{
    return 0 ;
}

int main() {

    void *  NodePNodeStr = NULL;
    f( myNode);

    return 0;
}
```

The aim of the code above is to get my doubt checked as to why macro replacement did not worked here . myNode seems to be not replaced by NodeP . The error I get in compilation is that `prog.cpp:14:5: error: 'myNodeNodeStr' was not declared in this scope f( myNode);` . However myNodeNodeStr should not have been searched but it should have searched for NodePNodeStr .

Can you tell me what mistake I am commiting and how to get around this one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to pass macros into macros, you have to take into account that an additional macro expansion will be required, since it will not be initially expanded as a parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define myNode NodeP
#define fp_(x) fp(x##NodeStr)
#define f(x) fp_(x)

int fp(void *  x)
{
    return 0 ;
}

int main() {

    void *  NodePNodeStr = NULL;
    f( myNode);

    return 0;
}
```

So to expand `f`, the pre-processor passes it `myNode`, which ends up with `fp_(myNode)`. And only now the pre-processor expands *all* the macros in this expression.

It works like that, because the primary use of the pre-processor is token generation (via the stringification and concatenation operators, `#` and `##`). So anything passed to the macro, can't be expanded immediately when those operators are involved.

Comment: Explanation is not entirely true because if the original macro had been `#define f(x) fp(x)` then `myNode` would have been expanded. Problem is with `##` operator which prevent expansion.

Answer (score 2):

The `##` operator takes macro parameters literally, so `myNode` isn't expanded into `NodeP` and the result is `myNodeNodeStr`.

When macro replacement gets deep, naked `##` isn't usually what you want. It's better to encapsulate it. An extra step of parameter-passing causes the expected expansion to happen.

```
#define CAT_LIT( A, B ) A ## B // Catenate literal tokens.
#define CAT( A, B ) CAT_LIT( A, B ) // Catenate fully-expanded parameters.
```

Then this will work properly:

```
#define f(x) CAT(x, NodeStr)
```